# File listing in Orchard CMS, client side?

Tags: download, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

One of my clients is asking to enable a "download section" in Orchard CMS. The idea is when a customer clicks in the download button in the main menu they will see a listing of folders and files.  So when they make click in a folder name, the folder will be opened and when they make click in the name of a file the file will be downloaded.

I have searched for a "download module" or "file listing module" in the Orchard gallery without any result.

Any idea about how to approach to the solution? maybe something with jquery but i am not sure if it is compatible with Orchard (I am a complete newbie in Orchard and ASP)

Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Try this search: http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Search?packageType=Modules&searchTerm=document

Comment: by the way, orchard 1.8.1 is out

Answer (score 2):

I think you missed this module: [Filemanager](http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.FileManager)
You can find a demo [here](http://www.mechacek.com/Contents/Item/Display/330)

Comment: Hey that looks exactly what I want! I already installed it but I can't see any changes in the admin section (How to put it on a menu, choose the root folder, etc). Do you know how can I activate the module or the way to use it? Can't find any documentation about it

Comment: You need to enable the module and then you can add a part to a page. This is explained here: http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Installing-and-upgrading-modules#WorkingwithModuleFeatures

Comment: Unfortunately even with the instructions I could not configure my Orchard, never found the way, but I think the answer were great, and I appreciate the dispostion of the user for helping me.